# How to increment a variable without it going back to 0

Tags: python

This is my code and every time I run it, it just goes back to 0 so it never adds it to the bank, i know it’s a stupid question but i’d appreciate some help. Thank you!

````
import random as r 

# get the start time
st = time.time()
bank=0


def work ():
 z=r.randint(1000,8000)
 global bank
 bank=bank+z
 jobs=[]
 y=r.choice(jobs)
 e=f"You worked as {y} and made {z} and you now have {bank} in your account"
 return e
print(work())

time.sleep(1)


 # get the end time
et = time.time()

 # get the execution time
elapsed_time = et - st
print('Execution time:', elapsed_time, 'seconds')```

How would I add it back to the original bank variable?
````

Comment: You need to save the bank value somewhere. Using a file for example.

Comment: Every time you run this program it will fail with an IndexError exception

Answer (score 0):

Frankly speaking, I don't quite understand what you mean, but I guess you may want to write like this

```
import random as r 
import time

# get the start time
st = time.time()
bank=0

while True:
    def work ():
        z=r.randint(1000,8000)
        global bank
        bank=bank+z
        jobs=['testjob']
        y=r.choice(jobs)
        e=f"You worked as {y} and made {z} and you now have {bank} in your account"
        return e
    print(work())

    time.sleep(1)

    # get the end time
    et = time.time()

    # get the execution time
    elapsed_time = et - st
    print('Execution time:', elapsed_time, 'seconds')

    stopflag = input('if you want work again ,plsea send 1 : ')
    if stopflag != '1' :
        break
```